# does DOM level 1/2/3 permit multi root element in DOMDocument?

Tags: xml, dom

I want to add more than one root element in a DOMDocument for some reason and output is as xml file which may looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<foo/>
<foo/>
```

I known the xml standard think this is not a well-format xml file, but I just wanted to known is that a possible to build a DOMDocument with multi root element?

Comment: by any DOM Level API.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR).

First, ["what is the DOM?"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/introduction.html)

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is an application programming interface (API) for valid HTML and well-formed XML documents.

How many root elements are allowed? DOM level [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-1590626202), [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1590626202), and [3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1590626202) all say the same thing in that regard:

> For XML and HTML, the node types, and which node types they may have as children, are as follows:
>   Document -- Element (maximum of one)...

---

So in short the answer is no, you cannot have multiple root elements in a conforming implementation.